# PL/SQL: Row isn't inserting

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm learning PL/SQL and I've created this procedure, which compiles; I'm not experiences enough with PL/SQL to spot where I went wrong:

Just to be clear, my question is, 'what did I do wrong?'

I'm using Datagrip and port forwarding to an OracleVM; I doubt there's a problem there, because I've inserted rows before, but this just isn't working.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE basket_add_sp
  (
    p_basketid IN bb_basketitem.idbasket%TYPE,
    p_prodid IN bb_basketitem.idproduct%TYPE,
    p_qty IN bb_basketitem.quantity%TYPE,
    p_price IN bb_basketitem.price%TYPE,
    p_size IN bb_basketitem.option1%TYPE,
    p_form IN bb_basketitem.option2%TYPE
  )
  IS
  BEGIN
  INSERT INTO BB_BASKETITEM(idbasketitem, idproduct, quantity, price, idbasket, option1, option2)
    VALUES (bb_idBasketitem_seq.NEXTVAL, p_prodid, p_qty, p_price, p_basketid, p_size, p_form);
  COMMIT;
END;
```

Which completes.

```
[2016-07-21 21:18:28] completed in 18ms
```

I run the procedure:

```
BEGIN
  basket_add_sp(14,8,1,10.80,2,4);
END;
```

Also completes.

```
[2016-07-21 21:18:39] completed in 14ms
```

But when I check the table to verify, no rows are returned.

```
SELECT * FROM BB_BASKETITEM WHERE IDBASKETITEM = 14;
```

Returns this:

[image]

However, when I check the table, there are other rows there.

```
SELECT * FROM BB_BASKETITEM WHERE IDBASKETITEM = 20;
```

Returns this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM BB_BASKETITEM WHERE IDPRODUCT = 8;
```

`IDBASKETITEM` is a unique ID that Oracle generates by sequence when you do the insert.

Comment: That does show all `IDPRODUCT` which are 8, but why won't `IDBASKETITEM` 14 display? I did insert a new row with it as PK, didn't I? Why isn't that working? Sorry, I'm just very confused why I don't get a row with 14 as IDBASKETITEM.

Comment: Yes, you passed in `p_basketid` as a parameter to the function.. but the first value in the insert statement doesn't use `p_basketid`.. instead it uses a value that it gets from the Oracle sequence `bb_idBasketitem_seq.NEXTVAL`

Comment: Oh, okay, I see it now, can't believe I missed it - thanks a ton!

Comment: Sure thing. Best of luck with the rest!